# why is my menu not showing an inside list brand?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**
This is my HTML source code where I want to make a menu list with flexbox and grid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dmghdfjb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <header>
      <div id="brand">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/22.jpg"></a>
        <ul class="menulist">
          <li class="list"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="list square"><a href=entry.html>Booking</a></li>
          <li class="list square"><a href="#">Resturant</a></li>
          <li class="list square"><a href="over.html">Overview</a></li>
          <li class="list square"><a href="signup">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EC8C01;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
}
#brand{
    width: 200px;
    height: 98px;
}
#brand > a > img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#menu{
    display: flex;
}
.menulist{
    background-color: red;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5,100px);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    justify-content: end;
}
.list{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
```

In the above code, My menu list not showing in the brand area. I want to make a menu list that is fixed inside ` without using position property of CSS. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```css
   *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    header{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #EC8C01;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        align-content: center;
    }
    #brand{
        width: 200px;
        height: 98px;
    }
    #brand > a > img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .menu-wrapper{
        margin-top: 24px;
    }
    #menu{
        display: flex;
    }
    .menulist{
        background-color: red;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5,100px);
        grid-gap: 5px;
        justify-content: end;
        /*float: right;*/
        margin-right: 34px;
    }
    .list{
        background-color: green;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 40px;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>dmghdfjb</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <style type="text/css">
      
        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <header>
          <div id="brand">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="https://www.internetkatta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo350.png"></a>
           
          </div>
          <div class="menu-wrapper">
               <ul class="menulist">
              <li class="list"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li class="list square"><a href=entry.html>Booking</a></li>
              <li class="list square"><a href="#">Resturant</a></li>
              <li class="list square"><a href="over.html">Overview</a></li>
              <li class="list square"><a href="signup">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is no use of `float:right;`
@aviboy.

Comment: but you want to move to extrem right of window right ? this will only place next to logo only.

Answer (score 0):

See this works for you.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EC8C01;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
}
#brand{
    width: 200px;
    height: 98px;
}
#brand > a > img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.menu-wrapper{
    margin-top: 24px;
}
#menu{
    display: flex;
}
.menulist{
    background-color: red;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5,100px);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    justify-content: end;
        float: right;
    margin-right: 34px;
}
.list{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dmghdfjb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

</head>
<body>

    <header>
      <div id="brand">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="https://www.internetkatta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo350.png"></a>
       
      </div>
      <div class="menu-wrapper">
           <ul class="menulist">
          <li class="list"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="list square"><a href=entry.html>Booking</a></li>
          <li class="list square"><a href="#">Resturant</a></li>
          <li class="list square"><a href="over.html">Overview</a></li>
          <li class="list square"><a href="signup">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aviboy i think grid and flex-box are used so that programer can leave float point and clearfix.
So, is there any need to use it.
**"The CSS Grid Layout Module offers a grid-based layout system, with rows and columns, making it easier to design web pages without having to use floats and positioning."** and **"The Flexible Box Layout Module, makes it easier to design flexible responsive layout structure without using float or positioning."** 
these above quote taken from w3schools.com.

Comment: Yes can do. I did easiest approach to solve question

Comment: ok well after follow your code in my file my problem is that it is also taking scrollbar in bottom.
Should i use min-width?

Comment: Yes you can. Can add screenshot ?

Comment: why have you used `float:right` in above code because if you close `</div>` inside image brand then it autoatically will be adjust in header container .

Comment: moving right side we have to use ```float:right```. Keeping both element separately created two div block.

Comment: Aviboy can you please help me
i am unable to place question here what shuold i do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214877/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-skshivangi).

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if I am understanding your point completely So giving answer in points.

If you just want to hide the scroll bar at the bottom you can use ::-webkit-scrollbar pseudo-element in the CSS [MDN blog for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar.

If you just don't want to have any elements outside the screen you can always use overflow in the CSS to limit that. [MDN blog for Overflow CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow)

For better flow than just the overflow, you will have to start designing your pages in a more responsive way.